# To Display the attributes, which are taken from the array of objects, flattened in Jolt Transform

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have below jolt input,

```json
{
  "citycode": "34343",
  "branch": "cityname",
  "changeDatetime": 1677063272522,
  "Marks": "L",
  "designations": [
    {
      "designation": "security ",
      "Language": "de"
    },
    {
      "designation": "officer",
      "Language": "fr"
    },
    {
      "designation": "superior",
      "Language": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output is:

```json
{
  "citycode" : "34343",
  "branch" : "cityname",
  "Marks" : "L",
  "LANGUAGE-ID" :  "de", 
  "Occupation" : "security",
  "LANGUAGE-ID" :  "fr",
  "Occupation" : "officer",
  "LANGUAGE-ID" : "en",
  "Occupation" : "superior"
}
```

current jolt output is below:

```
{
  "citycode" : "34343",
  "branch" : "cityname",
  "Marks" : "L",
  "LANGUAGE-ID" : [ "de", "fr", "en" ],
  "Occupation" : [ "security ", "officer", "superior" ]
}
```

Need to split the array elements separately.
Can you please help

Comment: Hi Sathk. 1. The desired output is invalid JSON as having repeated key names nested within the same object. 2. Can you please add how did you get the current output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current desired JSON output is invalid, but presumably you need the following one

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // all elements other than the "designations" array
      "designations": {
        "*": { // loop through the indexes of the "designations" array
          "L*": "LANGUAGE-ID_&1",
          "d*": "Occupation_&1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which suffixes incremental(0,1,2) indexes per each `LANGUAGE-ID` and `Occupation` key

Comment: Hi Barbaros Özhan: As always, thank you so much :) , the JOLT champ..

Comment: Hi Barbaros, here only 3 designations and language. Suppose if we have 10 designations and corresponding languages , and from that if we want only 5 , then how that is possible?

Comment: Hi @SATHK . In that case, we would need a common criteria applied as much as possibile.